# Pic 16F913 UART communications setup

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I've attached my code below (I'm blinking a LED to be able to see that the loop is occurring BTW).

I am not getting any data sent out over the UART, I have the Pic 16F913, and pin 17 is the output I'm trying to get, I have it hooked up to a RF-42N bluetooth module, I know the module works, because if I connect the rx to the tx, I get an echo. I then tried the following setup to send the letter "z" to the bluetooth module (and hopefully read on my phone, using blueterm).
I am getting no data, I don't know what the default FOSC is set to, so I've tried various values for the SPBRG hoping that i would be able to "guess" the right one, but none of them have seemed to work.

I'm using the Hi-Tech C compiler (Free version).

I hope this is enough information for everyone, I just have no clue what I am missing, I"ve been fighting this for hours.

// Main file

```c
#include <uart.h>

__CONFIG(INTIO & WDTDIS & PWRTEN & MCLRDIS & UNPROTECT & UNPROTECT & BORDIS & IESODIS & FCMDIS);


int i, j;
void wait(int z);




int main()
{

PORTA = 0x0;
CMCON0 = 7;
// Turn off Comparators
ANSEL = 0; 
// Turn off ADC
// Trisa4/5 0's mean output, 1's mean input
TRISA4 = 0;
// Make RA4/RA5 Outputs
TRISA5 = 0;


setupAsyncUart();
while (1==1)
{
    RA4 = 0;
    send('Z');
    wait(100);
    RA4 = 1;
    wait(100);
}
}

// Wait routine.
void wait(int z)
{
    for (int a=0; a<z; a++)
    {
        for (int b=0; b<z; b++)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

// uart.h

```c
void send(char string)
{
    TXREG = string;
}    
void setupAsyncUart(int BAUDRATE)
{
    SPBRG = 10;
    BRGH = 1; //Low speed = 0 high speed = 1
    SYNC = 0;
    SPEN = 1;
    TXEN = 1;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off all you must to set the internal oscillator to appropriate CPU frequency.

So set first in __CONFIG register bits FOSC<2:0> = (100) to select internal oscillator, after that set at very beginning of program the bits IRCF2, IRCF1 and IRCF0 in OSCCON register to desired oscillator frequency, default frequency is 4Mhz.

Than init the UART

1. Initiate CPU pins because some pins are shared with other MCPU periphery.
2. Load into SPBRG register proper number depend on your baud rate and
   CPU clock frequency (check datasheet).
3. Set BRGH bit in register TXSTA depend on desired baud rate generator
   (check datasheet).

EDIT:

To config internal clock use:

```
#include <htc.h>
__CONFIG(INTIO)
```

You should find all other bit declarations in "pic16f91x.h" file.

```
// Configuration Mask Definitions
#define CONFIG_ADDR 0x2007
// Oscillator 
#define EXTCLK      0x3FFF  // External RC Clockout
#define EXTIO       0x3FFE  // External RC No Clock
#define INTCLK      0x3FFD  // Internal RC Clockout
#define INTIO       0x3FFC  // Internal RC No Clock
#define EC          0x3FFB  // EC
#define HS          0x3FFA  // HS
#define XT          0x3FF9  // XT
#define LP          0x3FF8  // LP
// Watchdog Timer 
#define WDTEN       0x3FFF  // On
#define WDTDIS      0x3FF7  // Disabled / SWDTEN control
// Power Up Timer 
#define PWRTDIS     0x3FFF  // Off
#define PWRTEN      0x3FEF  // On
// Master Clear Enable 
#define MCLREN      0x3FFF  // MCLR function is enabled
#define MCLRDIS     0x3FDF  // MCLR functions as IO
// Code Protect 
#define UNPROTECT       0x3FFF  // Code is not protected
#define CP          0x3FBF  // Code is protected
#define PROTECT     CP  //alternate
// Data EE Read Protect 
#define UNPROTECT       0x3FFF  // Do not read protect EEPROM data
#define CPD         0x3F7F  // Read protect EEPROM data
// Brown Out Detect 
#define BORDIS      0x3CFF  // BOD and SBOREN disabled
#define SWBOREN     0x3DFF  // SBOREN controls BOR function (Software control)
#define BORXSLP     0x3EFF  // BOD enabled in run, disabled in sleep, SBOREN disabled
#define BOREN       0x3FFF  // BOD Enabled, SBOREN Disabled
// Internal External Switch Over Mode 
#define IESOEN      0x3FFF  // Enabled
#define IESODIS     0x3BFF  // Disabled
// Monitor Clock Fail-safe 
#define FCMEN       0x3FFF  // Enabled
#define FCMDIS      0x37FF  // Disabled
// In-Circuit Debugger Mode 
#define DEBUGEN     0x2FFF  // Enable ICD2 debugging
#define DEBUGDIS        0x3FFF  // Disable ICD2 debugging
```

OSCCON definition you should find in "cas16f913.h" file...

```
OSCCON                                 equ 008Fh
#define SCS_bit                        BANKMASK(OSCCON), 0
#define LTS_bit                        BANKMASK(OSCCON), 1
#define HTS_bit                        BANKMASK(OSCCON), 2
#define OSTS_bit                       BANKMASK(OSCCON), 3
#define IRCF0_bit                      BANKMASK(OSCCON), 4
#define IRCF1_bit                      BANKMASK(OSCCON), 5
#define IRCF2_bit                      BANKMASK(OSCCON), 6
```

Comment: I am not sure how to go about doing this I tried FOSC2 (in the config line) but that didn't work, I tried FOSC<2:0> = 100 in the config line, can you clarify "how" to do it? like what the Config line should look like? (maybe how I can figure this one out on my own would be nice too)

Comment: OK, I have added where to find declarations... :)

Comment: Turns out I'll need to use an external oscillator, I got ahold of a 16Mhz crystal from a friend, I just need to figure out how I plan to actually connect it, once that is done, I can verify your suggestion, and actually mark it as correct if it works out for me.... :) Sorry for the long delay

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure that your TX function will work, use it this way :

```
void vTxChar (unsigned char ucByte)
 {
   while (!TXIF);   //Waits for previous transfer to be done
   TXREG = ucByte;  //Loads TXREG with your value
 }
```

This while loop checks the transmit interrupt flag (even if not set) to see if the TXREG is empty or still set with previous value.

Depending on your XTAL frequency, your SPBRG value will vary, calculate it correctly then check with a computer if you have the right baudrate value.

```
16MHZ, BRGH=1, your SPBRG value for 9600 BDS = 0x68.
```